# Is VMWare Management Server, VMWare Hypervisor, or both, required in order to run Acronis vmProtect?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere, vmware-workstation, acronis

I am an individual freelance programmer who wishes to install [VMWare vSphere Essentials Kit](http://www.vmware.com/products/datacenter-virtualization/vsphere/small-business/compare-kits.html) on my (single) server machine, in conjunction with [Acronis vmProtect](http://www.acronis.eu/enterprise/products/vmprotect/).

The sole reason I want to run these two applications is so that I can have a robust way to back up my VMWare Workstation virtual machines, in case my OS dies and I need to reinstall.  Previous attempts to manually back up the VM folders through a standard backup program turned out to not be robust when I tried to download the backups and reinstall.

In particular, I am unclear whether I need to install the Management Server, the Hypervisor, or both, in order for Acronis vmProtect to successfully back up my virtual machine images.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this question from the comments:

`I wish to back up my virtual machines using Acronis vmProtect in conjunction vSphere Essentials, and I would like to know if I need to install VMWare Management Server, VMWare Hypervisor, or both, to achieve these ends.`

The answer is "both"

Having vSphere without a hypervisor is like having a car without wheels. You can sit in it and smell the leather and poke at the pedals, but you won't go anywhere. vSphere controls your hypervisor. vSphere is an additional layer on top of your hypervisor, and is used for managing multiple hypervisors and clustering them alltogether into one logical unit (a datacenter and then a cluster, in vSphere speak).